# How to hard-reset samsung galaxy ace

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, system-error, hard-reset

I am trying to reset the phone, and when I reach the Android menu, I have a yellow alert at the bottom: `can't access to /system/csr/PTR/system`

Any ideas what should I do?

Thanks :)

Comment: turns out it's not really bothering the process, so I'm fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To hard reset samsung galaxy ace,

1. Turn off your phone
2. Press and hold volume up, home, power button at the same time.
3. The Recovery appears, use volume up/down to navigate, power to select
4. Navigate to wipe data/factory reset and select
5. Navigate to Yes - delete all user data and select

And now resetting... (Make a backup of your phone first)

Navigate to reboot system now and select to get out of recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide for resetting the Samsung Galaxy Ace:

- http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f777/guide-samsung-galaxy-ace-hard-reset-1247841/

If you are a fan of YouTube, here is a video that has the same info:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhyKJInJOPM

It is basically the same way you reset all of the Android devices:

> Settings --> Privacy --> Factory Reset --> Reset --> Yes, Erase everything

You might want to try to see if you can update your OS before you do a factory reset, just to make sure an update wouldn't fix the problem.